# app crashes when select image from gallery

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap

I need to select from from gallery to implement filters on it .
I open gallery in app with this code:

```
 var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
                    intent.setType("image/*")
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PERMISSION_CODE)
```

Activity Result:

```
 if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == PERMISSION_CODE) {
            var bitmap: Bitmap = BitmapUtils.getBitmapFromGallery(this, data?.data, 800, 800)
            original_filter_bitmap.recycle()
            final_bitmap.recycle()
            filtered_bitmap.recycle()
            original_filter_bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
            final_bitmap = original_filter_bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
            filtered_bitmap = original_filter_bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
            image_preview.setImageBitmap(original_filter_bitmap)
            bitmap.recycle()
         //   imageFiltersFragment.displayThumbNail(original_filter_bitmap)
        }
```

Here is get from bitmap from gallery method:

```
(Context context, Uri uri, int width, int height) {
        String[] filepathcolumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, filepathcolumn, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filepathcolumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);
    }
```

So gallery opens , i select image and when press to image app crushes.

Logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BitmapUtils.getBitmapFro…is, data?.data, 800, 800) must not be null
        at com.example.sg772.textonimage.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.kt:191)
```

line 191: `var bitmap: Bitmap = BitmapUtils.getBitmapFromGallery(this, data?.data, 800, 800)`

Comment: `data?.data` might be null, hence the `?`. Your operation is unsafe and is like a NullPointerException. Wrap your line with `data?.data?.let {}`.

Comment: instead of getting path you should retrive content from the uri  (please log with value of `picturePath` )

Comment: "Here is get from bitmap from gallery method:" -- get rid of the `query()`. Stop assuming that you can get a filesystem path from `MediaStore`. Instead, use `openInputStream()` on `ContentResolver`, and use that `InputStream` with `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`. Or, even better, use an existing image-loading library (Glide, Picasso, etc.) rather than doing all of this yourself on the main application thread.

Comment: @CommonsWare load image with help of Picasso ?

Comment: @androidev: Yes. Picasso knows how to load images from a `Uri` and populate an `ImageView` with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data?.data` might be null.

```
data?.data?.let {
    val bitmap = BitmapUtils.getBitmapFromGallery(this, it, 800, 800)
    ...
}
```

Comment: sorry , i dont understand how to implement this , where should i declare bitmap variable this your code ?

Comment: `with` is just a Kotlin keyword.. Edited without it.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked , but what is that construction (.let{}) how it differrs from usuall writing can you explain ?